# Dynamic content inside Trans Component i18next

Tags: reactjs, i18next, react-i18next

I have a list of translated keys and react component content.
e.g :

```
    list = [{ translation: "Hello <1>World</1>", content: "Hello <a href='#'>World</a>" },
{ translation: "A <1>B</1>", content: "A <a href='#'>B</a>" }]
```

The idea is to show a translated data from the list using the "translation" and the structure of "content" with Trans Component of i18next-react with a map function.

```
{list.map((item) => (
<Trans i18nKey={item.translation}>
    {item.content}
</Trans>))}
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work at all, the outcome is only the translated string, without the structure that should came by the React Component content.

Any idea how to work around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case anyone will try to do this in the future:
The way to do so is to use `components` props as Jamuhl mentioned.
And to pass there an array with the HTML elements of the "item.content".
The way to get the array of HTML elements from a string as we have on "item.content" is by using ReactHtmlParser that parse that string into an HTML elements array!
ReactHtmlParser can be cloned from here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser

Answer (score 1):

Your content is a pure string and not a react element. Therefore your code can't work -> it can't extract the `a` element from the string and replace the `<1>` with it.

> edit below

sample:

```
{list.map((item) => (
<Trans
  i18nKey={item.translation}
  defaults={item.translation} // Hello <0>World</>
  components={[<a href="#">World</a>]}
</Trans>))}
```

You need to pass in the components to get interpolated into the "pseudo" tags <0>...details also have a look at https://react.i18next.com/misc/using-with-icu-format (for props defaults, components, values)

Comment: Thanks. So I tried to convert my string to a react element with: `<Trans i18nKey={item.translation}>
      <div
       dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html:item.content}
      />
     </Trans>` But this doesnt seem to work unfortunatelly. What am I missing?

Comment: Yeah I've thought about that direction as well. But the thing is that `[<a href="#">World</a>]` is dynamic and not hardcoded, so I tried to do this `components={[item.content]}` or `components={item.content}`, or even `components={[{item.content}]}`. But none of them seem to be working for me.

Comment: This `components={[item.content]}` works good, but the thing is that the data of `item.content` was interpolated as a string and not as HTML element. so it prints - Hello World with no link. I can tell that it is treated as 2 separated elements, but still no link :(

Comment: I give up...you just insist on throwing your item.content anywhere -> where I show you that can't work with Trans...you need to adapt your content to make it work...or just use `<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={__html:item.content} />` without Trans

Comment: Really appreciate your help. I'm insisting on the `item.content` since this is a dynamic string and it comes in a form of an html. I'll think of a way to modify this into an array so then i will be able to use components prop thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For who still have problem.
make sure you have correct order of nested html

like

```
key ="<0><0/><1>translated here</1></0>";
function createMarkup()
{
return <div><input type="checkbox" /><label>translate here</label></div>;
}

<Trans i18nKey="key" >{ReactHtmlParser(createMarkup())}</Trans>
```

Comment: Your answer might be correct but still you need to improve on answering questions like formatting the code and explaining briefly about the solution.